Redshift COPY all PARQUET files from folder but not JSON files
We have a vendor that's putting JSON files into folders that have our target PARQUET files we want to load.  The folders have timestamps, so we have to load the whole folder.  But, COPY is failing when trying to also load those JSON files.  Is there a way to exclude the JSON files but load all the PARQUET files in the folder?
For example, the folder is s3://bucket/path/2024-06-07T12:44:44.79492.parquet/
So, my COPY command only copies up to s3://bucket/path/2024-06-07, because I don't know the timestamp a priori.

No, this is not doable out of the box.  You can
A: use manifest file listing all the individual files you want to copy or
B: create a S3 triggered Lambda that automatically either runs the copy command for the Parquet files against Redshift or moves the JSON files to another folder/bucket so you can run the copy command manually.

Ok, that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for posting this analysis!
